# How to translate Arabic numerals to Bengali

Tags: r, bookdown

I am testing the [bookdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/) R package for writing contents in Bengali language. I've started with the minimal book example in the [bookdown-demo-master](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo) repository.

When I build the book, I would like to show the Bengali numerals instead of the Arabic. That is, I would like to translate

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0

to

১, ২, ৩, ৪, ৫, ৬, ৭, ৮, ৯, ০

Ideally, the page numbers, chapter numbers, and the page references in the table of contents should show in Bengali instead of the default Arabic numerals.

Is there a way to achieve that? Thank you.

Comment: Trying to find documentation for what you are using could you link? Will updae answer with syntax needed if Dictionaries exist. Im not sure if this will work

Comment: This is my first question on Stackoverflow. So please excuse my ignorance.The link to the [minimal book example](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo) and the link to the [documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a dictionary object with the number being the tag and the bengali number being the value.

Then anytime you write a string maybe run it through a translation function that checks for the keys in the string. If they exist replace it with the value.

Comment: I am not certain if that is possible with bookdown.

Comment: Yeah doesn't seem like it. Looks like you may need to create a template that Uses the R code blocks to translate the page numbers and chapters to a different character. https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/r-code.html  and https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/templates.html